# SQL - OLAP Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, olap, ranking, row-number

I need to find "Transactions" within the data and generate sequence number for each transaction.

Each Transaction is defined as a check_in = 0 [which means a checkout ] and check_in = 1 [ which mean checkin] as one transaction - there can be "n" number of transactions in between, some can have check_in as null or check_in = 0

Sequence no should be same for the same transaction [ one transaction block]. I have data with Customer_ID, Check_in and Date. Need to generate the Sequence No.

```
Sequence No Customer_ID Check_in    Date
1               3252538     0       11/14/15 03:20 AM
1               3252538     0       11/14/15 07:37 PM
1               3252538     1       11/15/15 07:27 PM
2               3252538     0       11/17/15 12:34 AM
2               3252538     1       01/27/16 07:46 AM
3               3252538     0       02/01/16 09:09 PM
3               3252538     NULL    02/05/16 08:56 PM
3               3252538     1       02/05/16 11:24 PM
4               3252538     0       02/08/16 07:19 PM
4               3252538     0       02/13/16 02:16 AM
4               3252538     1       02/13/16 10:49 PM
5               3252538     0       02/16/16 06:07 PM
5               3252538     1       02/19/16 03:01 AM
```

How can this be done in a sql ?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting.  The "1" ends a transaction.  All the zeros before it define the transaction. You can identify the groups by doing an inverse sum of the 1s:

```
select t.*,
       sum(check_in) over (partition by customer_id order by date desc) as grp
from transactions t;
```

Unfortunately, this puts things in the reverse order.  So:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by grp) as sequence
from (select t.*,
             sum(check_in) over (partition by customer_id order by date desc) as grp
      from transactions t
     ) t;
```

Comment: "1" does not always end a transaction. There can be some mini-transactions within a Big Transaction, that can have all combination of 1 and 0 and null values for check_in. check_in = 0 followed by check_in=1 ends a transaction.

Comment: @SreedharReddy . . . In that case, why does sequence "2" start after 0-0-1?  It would appear that you need two *1*s to complete the first transaction.

Comment: 0-0-1 is check_in = 0 followed by a check_in = 1 which ends the first transaction.

Comment: @SreedharReddy . . . Hence "1" ends the transactions.

Comment: yes, when i think about it, you are right. I am using amazon redshift and it does not appear to support sum(check_in), Is there any other way this can be achieved?

Comment: @SreedharReddy . . . Convert it to a number from whatever type it is.